# Comparing strings up to column length (using index)

Tags: mysql

Basically what I want to do is to reverse the `column LIKE 'string%'` behavior. Consider following table:

```
CREATE TABLE texts (
    id int not null, 
    txt varchar(30) not null,
    primary key(id),
    key `txt_idx` (txt)
) engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO texts VALUES(1, 'abcd');
```

According to [B-Tree Index Characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-btree-hash.html) following query will utilize txt_idx index:

```
SELECT txt FROM texts WHERE txt LIKE 'abc%';
```

Now I want somewhat different behavior. I want the `'abcd'` row to be returned when queried for `'abcde'`. At the moment I've got stuck with this query:

```
SELECT txt FROM texts WHERE 'abcde' LIKE CONCAT(txt, '%');
```

Obviously (confirmed by explain) it does not utilize any index, but my intuition tells me it should be possible to compare particular value against index up to indexed value length (just like strncmp does).

The main reason for this is my huge table with domain entries. I want to select both "example.org" and "something.example.org" (but not "else.example.org") when querying for "www.something.example.org". Splitting and performing multiple queries or applying `OR` clauses seems to work too slow for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to convert it to the equivalent `IN` test:

```
WHERE txt IN ('a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde')
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that this can perform so much better than several 'OR' clauses - thanks!